# How to open PDFString in new window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to get a PDF string from the response, and showing in browser winow as a PDF. How to open PDFString in new window using javascript?

Here is the snippet am using.

> var newWindow = window.open('', 'newwin', 'width=400,height=500');
>               newWindow.document.open();
>               newWindow.document.write(response.responseText);
>               newWindow.document.close();

Comment: Please show the code that you already have.

Comment: @Andy updated with my snippets

Comment: By PDF string, are you talking about the URL of a PDF? If you can create a `jsfiddle` that would be handy.

Comment: Er... You are using several DOM functions, which are designed to manipulate HTML documents. You cannot use them to manipulate random binary data such as PDF files.